# Scrollbar behaviour is different is Firefox when using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, scrollbar

I have a page with a sidebar. The sidebar is placed in a flexbox column. The sidebar should show a (vertical) scrollbar if it's content cannot be shown on the page.

When the scrollbar is shown the width of the first column should be increase by the width of the scrollbar. This is the case in Chrome. However in Firefox the behaviour is different. In Firefox the scrollbar is placed over the content of the sidebar.

To illustrate the problem is created a codepen containing 2 flexbox containers, 1 showing a scrolbar.

```
[https://codepen.io/janaukema/pen/eYxmQJv][1]
```

**Chrome** show the following result:

[image]

Where **Firefox** does show:

[image]

How can I make firefox to use the same behaviour as Chrome does? I don't want the scrollbar to cover my.

I do not want to change the style or width of the scrollbar, but just want to increase the width of the sidebar if a scrollbar appears.